# Replacing anonymous function in javascript changing the way the code executes

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I have some javascript code that I am calling in casperJS, its quite short so I have included the whole listing

```
var links = []; 
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getLinks() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('table');
  return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
    return e.getAttribute('id');
  }); 
}

casper.start('example.html', function() {
  links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});

casper.run(function() {
  this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');
  this.echo(' - ' + links.join('\n - ')).exit();
});
```

This outputs the expected

```
3 links found:
 - table A
 - table B
 - table C
```

Whereas switching to breaking out the anonymous function in getLinks so that getLinks is replaced with the below two functions

```
function extract(e) {
  return e.getAttribute('id');
}

function getLinks() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('table');
  return Array.prototype.map.call(links, extract);
}
```

Yields

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'links.length')                  
  /Users/jrrpl/git/gamecock/download.js:18
  /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/modules/casper.js:408 in checkStep
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that the reference to the named function causes casper.run() to execute early. Anyone know why this would occur?

Comment: Those look like they are equivalent, so something else must be going on.

Comment: Please show us the code for how `links` is defined.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the anonymous function and the named `extract` function to compare what's going on? Inspecting some values of `e` in both places could be very informative.

Comment: There's also the possibility you have a variable name conflict.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` will never return `null`, nor will `Array.prototype.map`, so I think we're missing something. Is this a complete example, or did you change something to make it shorter?

Comment: A named function won't do anything of the sort. I'm guessing you're calling the function by doing `...map.call(links, extract())` instead of `...map.call(links, extract)`.  Only way a named function would make a difference would be if the code actually looked for the non-standard `.name` property of the function, which is very doubtful

Comment: I'm calling the function exactly as in the code above it has faithfully been copied and pasted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `this.evaluate(getLinks);`. [The docs state](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate):

> Basically [PhantomJS’ WebPage#evaluate](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) equivalent.
>
> ### Understanding evaluate()
>
> The concept behind this method is probably the most difficult to
>   understand when discovering CasperJS. As a reminder, think of the
>   evaluate() method as a gate between the CasperJS environment and the
>   one of the page you have opened; everytime you pass a closure to
>   evaluate(), you’re entering the page and execute code as if you were
>   using the browser console.

Even the PhantomJS docs don't state (any more? Did I miss it?) what exactly happens. [The source code](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/modules/webpage.js#L352) though is quite explicit:

> ```
> page.evaluate = function (func, args) {
>     var str, arg, argType, i, l;
>     if (!(func instanceof Function || typeof func === 'string' || func instanceof String)) {
>         throw "Wrong use of WebPage#evaluate";
>     }
>     str = 'function() { return (' + func.toString() + ')(';
>     for (i = 1, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++) {
>         …
>         str += JSON.stringify(arg) + ",";
>         …
>     }
>     str = str.replace(/,$/, '') + '); }';
>     return this.evaluateJavaScript(str);
> };
> ```

No we also see why it is required that all arguments to the function need to be serializable: The whole thing is converted to a code string that is then injected in the page - "executed as if it was pasted into the console".

This means that **closures do not work**, and you will end up with `extract` being undefined in the page. If you did use

```
function getLinks() {
    function extract(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('id');
    }
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('table');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, extract);
}
```

then it should work.